# HTML5 canvas smearing image patterns when translating

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Weird issue when using 'no-repeat', 'repeat-x' or 'repeat-y' when creating a pattern using an image.
Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {        

        context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.translate(50,50);
        
        var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'no-repeat');
        context.fillStyle = pattern;
        context.fill();
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/wood-pattern.png';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm translating the image pattern within the shape (in this case it's a rectangle, but it occurs for any shape). On Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m, it causes a 'smearing' of the image. Is there a way to avoid the smear effect or am I doing something insanely wrong.

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bHcL9/5/)

screen shot:
[image: Example Screen Shot]

Comment: Also confirmed this happens in FireFox 29.0.1

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2mq2792/8

Answer (score 2):

`context.translate` applies to the starting point to draw on the canvas.  Instead you want to fill a certain portion of the rectangle.

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
  var width = 600;
  var height = 400;
  var patOffsetX = 50;
  var patOffsetY = 50;

  context.rect(0, 0, width, height);

  var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
  context.fillStyle = pattern;
  context.fillRect(patOffsetX, patOffsetY, width - patOffsetX, height - patOffsetY);
  context.stroke(); //added to help see the rect
};
```

I also updated the size of the canvas to see it working.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bHcL9/9/)

Comment: No, you miss understand; I am not trying to translate the rectangle and draw the pattern: I am trying to draw a rectangle and within that rectangle, position the pattern. This pattern can be translated, rotated and scaled. For example, suppose this rectangle was to have a border, the pattern filling that rectangle should be offset by (50,50) but not the containing rectangle.

Comment: So like this(I added a stroke to see the rect better)?... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHcL9/2/)

Comment: Not quite; the pattern falls out of the rectangle you had drawn; I'm sorry, the example I gave should have been a rectangle that is smaller then the canvas to properly convey the idea better.

Comment: If you're just doing 1 non-repeating image then you don't need the pattern at all.  Just (1) context.save (2) draw a rect (3) context.clip (4) draw your image clipped inside the rect. (5) context.restore. BTW, context.translate only affects drawings after the translate, not existing drawings.  So in your question's code the rect will not be affected because it was defined before the translate.  The difference you're seeing between browsers is that some browsers will resolve the translate later in the drawing process.

Comment: The 'repeat' is a option that will change; to simply draw a single image and clipping it will not suffice (unless I can calculate how many times it must be repeated either along the 'x' or 'y' or both axis, which I was hoping to avoid with the 'createPattern' method).

Comment: @ni3po42 Are you looking to start the pattern at a certain offset then have it repeat and fill in the rest of the rectangle?

Comment: Yes, start the pattern at a certain offset and have it repeat.

Comment: I figured out a workaround, but it might be a little heavy on the memory then I care for; so I'll be changing my application to use simple clipping with to simulate the 'no-repeat' option and use the createPattern for 'repeat'. I'll just disallow 'repeat-x' and 'repeat-y' for now. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your task using clipping

- Save the context state.
- Draw a boundary rectangle.
- Clip future drawing to inside the boundary rectangle.
- Draw another offset rectangle inside the boundary rectangle using your image as a pattern.
- Restore the context to its unclipped state.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fHKLk/

[image]

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house16x16.png";
    function start(){

        // create a pattern
        var pattern = context.createPattern(img,'repeat');

        // save the unclipped context state
        context.save();

        // draw the boundary rect
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(20,20,200,200);
        context.stroke();

        // clip future drawing to inside the boundary rect
        context.clip();

        // draw a 2nd rect with a 50px offset from the boundary rect
        // and using your image pattern
        context.fillStyle=pattern;
        context.fillRect(20+50,20+50,300,300);

        // restore the context to its unclipped state
        context.restore();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```